# Summing Delayed Cashflows - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

A company has a list of clients, i, all of which delay their payments by X_i. The problem is to create a spreadsheet that will show the sum of positive cashflows for a given day, where the delay of incoming cashflows can be manually adjusted.

The input is:

| Date | Amount Due $ | Client | Expected Delay (Days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 100 | A | 2 |
| 02 | 5 | B | 0 |
| 02 | 30 | C | 1 |
| 03 | 50 | B | 0 |

The output needs to be:

| Date | Total Inflows $ |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 0 |
| 02 | 5 |
| 03 | 180 |

How can I code this in Google Sheets?

Comment: Can you explain logic to gain `Total Inflows $`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for date:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A)
```

and for totals:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(F2:F),SUMIF(A2:A+D2:D,F2:F,B2:B),))
```

if in date column you have text values you need convert it to real dates and format as you want

[image]